# calling a method after each 60 seconds in iPhone

Tags: iphone, timer, nstimer, gksession

I have created an GKSession and as its object is created, it starts search for availability of devices, as

```
 - (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {
```

I want to call this method after each 60 seconds, what should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a count down Timer for cocos2d?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446717/how-can-i-create-a-count-down-timer-for-cocos2d)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

After each 60.0 second , iOS will call the below function

```
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    NSLog(@"red");
}
```

Comment: but this is delegate method, called whenever state changed, like from available to unavailabe,

Comment: @Jhaliya: Will it work everytime i.e. if I implement this NSTimer in app delegate, I want the method to be called irrespective of viewcontroller I am in & irrespective of the app state whether in foreground, background or killed.

Answer (score 13):

Once you set NSTimer to scheduleWithTimeInterval it calls it immediately.
You can use

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0f];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
 NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                               selector: @selector(timerFired:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

 - (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer{
 if(condition){
       [theTimer isValid]; //recall the NSTimer
       //implement your methods
  }else{
      [theTimer invalidate]; //stop the NSTimer
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in 
print("That took a minute")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use schedular method...

```
-(void) callFunction:(CCTime)dt 
{
    NSLog(@"Calling...");
}
```

you can call above function by using this...

```
[self schedule:@selector(callFunction:) interval:60.0f];
```

Comment: Yeah..you can unschedule this method whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.0**

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func updateTimer() {
   print("1 min passed")
}
```