# How can I trigger a method every 10 seconds without using NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I would like to call a method every 10 seconds, but I want to use something other than NSTimer.  What could I use to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use timers? An NSTimer seems like a perfect solution to this problem.

Comment: As a note, Xcode is an IDE, not a framework or language, so please refrain from tagging your questions with it and placing it in the title unless you are asking about the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Cocos2D, you have to use a NSTimer to do this....

If you are using Cocos2D, use the schedule method

here's a link below that shows both :

[How can I create a count down timer for cocos2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446717/how-can-i-create-a-count-down-timer-for-cocos2d)

Comment: Why would you "have" to use an NSTimer if you're not using Cocos2D?

Answer (score 11):

I know you said you didn't want to use timers, but just to make sure you know how simple it would be with a timer...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(someMethod)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Comment: because I want that a ball start moving every ten second but I think aI can't have to timers for the same method

Comment: I don't think that's a problem - but even if it is, just create `anotherMethod` that calls `someMethod` :)

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to use the timer, you can use GCD which internally will make use of NSOperationQueue, nevertheless will work in all cases. For eg: i had a class which was inherited from NSOperation so the above methods didn't work so i had go go with GCD:

```
    double delayInSeconds = 3.0;      
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);    
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_after(popTime, queue, ^{
        [self methodYouWantToCall];  
    });
```

The above code calls the method methodYouWantToCall after every three seconds.

Comment: "GCD which internally will make use of NSOperationQueue" This is not correct. It is vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a loop with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` setting afterDelay to 10.0.

I don't recommend this though, use an NSTimer.

```
- (void)callMeEvery10Seconds
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(callMeEvery10Seconds) 
               withObject:nil 
               afterDelay:10.0];

    // ... code comes here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is:

```
- (void)scheduleLoopInSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)delayInSeconds
{
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_after(popTime, queue, ^{
        [self callWhatEverMethodYouWant];
        [self shceduleLoopcaInSeconds:delayInSeconds];//set next iteration
    });

}

// now whenever you like call this, and it will be triggering  "callWhatEverMethodYouWant" every 10 secs.
[self shceduleLoopcaInSeconds:10.0];
```

Comment: WOW, I have tested this method and it works ok but the CPU usage that was around 25% with NSTimer skyrocketed to 99%!!! WTF? I guess this is called by the overhead associated with dispatching the blocks!