# How to Automatically call a method for every 1 second in iOS.?

Tags: ios

I want to write some code in a method in iOS and that method should be called for every 1 sec.
Can anyone help me to do this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is very common question. no need to ask here. U can found this easyly by searching google or SO old question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674375/calling-a-method-after-each-60-seconds-in-iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446717/how-can-i-create-a-count-down-timer-for-cocos2d

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(thisIsCalledEvery1Second:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

Read Apple docs for [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Where i add this code

Comment: @vijay add where you want to fire action.viewdidload or button action

Comment: Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: , repeats: true, block: { (timer) in 
print("That took a second")
})